# Angular 5 NgFor - Looping through Elements and Detecting Elements Already Rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have created a stoplight with (red, yellow, green) circles displayed depending on values passed from a database.

Currently, I am displaying status of reports using colors. ***NgFor loop works well to place the colors where they belong if there is only 1 object in array.** If a reportId(report) is not in the data, a "green" circle appears which is how it should appear. There should only be 3 colors displaying at one time and not repeated.

The problem is, if there is a second object in the values array, the loop ignores the previous values and displays a green circle where it should be ignored since a value already exists for that reportId. Like stated, if there is only 1 object in the 'values' array, it works perfect and the green circle is applied and placed in the right spot of the non existing reportID's, however when there is more than one object/report listing, it gives me a second row of stoplights, ignoring the set value from the first iteration. Infact, it will treat the previous reportID as if it never existed and place a green circle.

Any ideas of how to solve this? I looked into ASYNC pipe but not 100% sure how to apply it in this scenario.

[image]

Data looks like this:

```
{ key: 'Profit Loss', 
  value: [{ yellow: 'Y', red: 'N', reportId: 2 }]
},
{ key: 'Actuals', 
  value: [{ yellow: 'N', red: 'Y', reportId: 2 },
          { yellow: 'Y', red: 'N', reportId: 1 }]
}
```

And the Loop is structured like so...

```
            <div *ngFor="let siteMap of reportRow; let i = index;" >
               {{ siteMap.key }}
            <div *ngFor="let pMap of siteMap.value; let xi = index;" >
                <!---Report 1---->
                <!--------------->
                <tr *ngIf="pMap.yellow === 'Y' && pMap.reportId === 1">
                  <td><span class="yellowcolor"></span> <b>Report 1 Yellow</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="pMap.red === 'Y' && pMap.reportId === 1">
                  <td><span class="redcolor"></span> <b>Report 1 Red</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="pMap.reportId !== 1">
                  <td><span  class="greencolor"></span><b>Report 1 Green</b></td>
                </tr>
                <!---Report 2---->
                <!--------------->
                <tr *ngIf="pMap.yellow === 'Y' && pMap.reportId === 2">
                  <td><span class="yellowcolor"></span> <b>Report 2 Yellow</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="pMap.red === 'Y' && pMap.reportId === 2">
                  <td><span class="redcolor"></span> <b>Report 2 Red</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="pMap.reportId !== 2">
                  <td><span  class="greencolor"></span> <b>Report 2 Green</b></td>
                </tr>
                <!---Report 3---->
                <!--------------->
                <tr *ngIf="pMap.yellow === 'Y' && pMap.reportId === 3">
                  <td><span class="yellowcolor"></span> <b>Report 3 Yellow</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="pMap.red === 'Y' && pMap.reportId === 3">
                  <td><span class="redcolor"></span> <b>Report 3 Red</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="pMap.reportId !== 3">
                  <td><span  class="greencolor"></span> <b>Report 3 Green</b></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why dont you just push the report ID's drawn to a new array when drawing, then you can omit them from repeating if it already exist in the drawn report ID array.

Comment: How would i go about that? I am able to push the id's to an array but would i omit them in the component or the html? Can you create an answer @Nugu

Comment: Lets say you were able to create an array having already drawn report Ids, 
then you could have another `*ngIf` after looping for siteMap.

`<div *ngFor="let pMap of siteMap.value; let xi = index;">
  <div *ngIf="!newArray.includes(pMap.reportId)">
     ...
  </div>
</div>`

Comment: does this newArray.includes check belong on the "greenColor" element? Im slightly confused. @Nugu

Comment: @Nugu i think i understand what you're saying. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @Nugu your idea worked. I combined the found repIds and used includes() which worked fine! Create an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MizAkita Posting the comment as an answer, since the solution worked.

Lets say you were able to create an array having already drawn report Ids, then you could have another `*ngIf` after looping for `siteMap`.

```
<div *ngFor="let pMap of siteMap.value; let xi = index;"> 
   <div *ngIf="!newArray.includes(pMap.reportId)"> ... </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have multiple solutions for this, but what I would do is move the complex part to the javascript:

sort and fill array before rendering :

```
ngOnInit() {

    let rawData = this.myService.get();

    for (let siteMap of rawData) {
        siteMap.value.sort(this.compare);
    }
    this.fillEmptyData(rawData);
    this.reportRow = rawData;
}

private compare(a,b) {
  if (a.reportId < b.reportId)
    return -1;
  if (a.reportId > b.reportId)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

private fillEmptyData(dataToFill) {
    for (let column of dataToFill) {
        if (!column.value) {
            column.value = [];
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (!column.value[i] || column.value[i].reportId !== (i + 1)) {
                // column.value[i] does not contain the expected reportId
                let emptyItem = {
                    reportId: i + 1,
                    reportName: 'Report ' + (i + 1), // or whatever
                    empty: true
                };
                // insert the empty item at the place it should be
                column.value.splice(i, 0, emptyItem);
            } else {
                column.value[i].reportName = 'Report ' + (i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you will purge your html part :

```
<div *ngFor="let siteMap of reportRow; let i = index;" >
   {{ siteMap.key }}
    <div *ngFor="let pMap of siteMap.value; let xi = index;" >
        <tr *ngIf="pMap.yellow === 'Y'">
          <td><span class="yellowcolor"></span> <b>{{pMap.reportName}} Yellow</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="pMap.red === 'Y'">
          <td><span class="redcolor"></span> <b>{{pMap.reportName}} Red</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="pMap.empty === true">
          <td><span  class="greencolor"></span><b>{{pMap.reportName}} Green</b></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the result:
[image: Result]

Comment: What if the reportId's change? This solution seems to iterate through the ID's. I would prefer a way to do this in the html forloop but I may be forced to perform this in the component.

Comment: @MizAkita what do you mean by "change" ? You mean you retrieve data multiple times ? So you may use what I wrote to initialize the array, and then, make a new method to update data instead of building them from scratch

Comment: im having a tough time getting this to work. I am already sorting and formatting my data in the component to build the named object reportRow so i wouldn't need a subscribe method... how do i use my formatted ReportRow (see original question for its strucutre)  in place of your myservice.get() initial call?

Comment: @MizAkita If you master how reportRow is built, then you may do what I suggested at the very beginning, and so you wouldn't need to sort/fill it. And the fact it is not an async call makes it easier, see my edited answer

Comment: ok this slightly works but buggy. The problem is, is my report names (listed on each line of colored circles), (not necessarily the ones listed in the above question) are unique to the number. They shouldn't be iterated. Also, it doesn't look like the .sort() is allowing a array of objecfts like i have in my question. How would i fix this to work against data structur3d like mine. Im getting a .sort() error.

Comment: @MizAkita Indeed, you have to loop on sitemaps before sorting, didn't notice that, see my edited answer.

Comment: If you cannot iterate on reportIds, how do you know which numbers are green ? You must have a list of valid reportIds, and you can then loop on it...

Comment: Please read the original question... The green ones are generated when a report 1, 2 or 3 is missing. @Random

Comment: @MizAkita Ah, you mean the report name is more complicated than in the example ? then you should add a property 'reportName' as in my edited answer

Comment: yes... for the sake of not disclosing what the report is, i used "Report 1", "Report 2", "Report 3" but really its an actual name associated with the ReportId.

Comment: sortedData is missing... where is this coming from? Trying my hardest to get this to work.

Comment: @MizAkita this is rawData, missed to rename it when removed the `.subscribe()` part

Comment: Almost got it working... how do i set a name value for all three reports? @Random

Comment: you said you mastered the construction of the object from start, don't you ? otherwise, just add an else in the last if: `} else { column[i].name = 'toto'; }`

Comment: I dont remember saying i mastered anything @Random - still working on it getting it to work.

Comment: @MizAkita you said "I am already sorting and formatting my data in the component to build the named object reportRow"

Comment: yes i am. That is how i get the data objects i posted. They are constructed from a few filters and formatted to work the way they are created.

Comment: @Compare - im getting no errors and its mapping the other vals but not sending me back the green circle. I'm assuming its because of compare. Did you test this solution?

Comment: i was never able to get this working. The green color never displayed and you have missing pieces of code... this.compare() accepts two params but none are given. Too bad.

Comment: @MizAkita you must not give parameters to compare, this is a normal behavior, the code is `siteMap.sort(this.compare)`, not `siteMap.sort(this.compare())`. You are giving the function signature to the sort method, then the sort method will give the 2 expected parameters to the compare function.

Comment: I'll give it a try to make it work with your sample data

Comment: @MizAkita it works well for me after changing column to column.value in the filling method, and changing this.data to this.reportRow at the end of ngOnInit.